# Closed form for $c_m = \sum_{n=|m|}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2n} (-1)^{m+n}{2n \choose m+n}$, $m$ integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, fourier-series, hypergeometric-function

What is a closed form for

$c_m = \sum_{n=|m|}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2n} (-1)^{m+n}{2n \choose m+n}$

with $m$ an integer?  (N.B. the starting index is an absolute value.)

I already know a form in terms of a hypergeometric function, but that's really just rewriting the sum as another sum.

This series arose near the end of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2984718/441161

For any particular $m$, this sum is scaling and summing the terms down a *vertical* column of the Pascal's triangle that has alternating signs, and is only operating on columns that have elements in the even rows of Pascal's triangle -- rows with coefficients for $(a-b)^{2n}$.

$m = 0$ corresponds to the center column of Pascal's triangle.  $m = 1$ corresponds to the first relevant column to the right of the center column of Pascal's triangle.    $m = -1$ corresponds to the first relevant column to the left of the center column of Pascal's triangle.  And so on...

Answer (score 0):

If $m \ge 0$ I get $$ \frac{(3-2\sqrt{2})^m}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and if $m < 0$, 
$$ \frac{(3+2\sqrt{2})^m}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that $c_{m} = c_{-m}$.  Maybe that's the case with your answer, but I'm not at a place I can easily check that at the moment.  Or maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: The sum from $m$ to $\infty$ is $(3-2\sqrt{2})^m/\sqrt{2}$, the sum from $-m$ to $\infty$ is $(3+2\sqrt{2})^m/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: There are absolute value bars there in the lower limit (intentionally): $n=|m|$, if that is the discrepancy.  I only need the sum from $|m|$ to $\infty$. BTW, what techniques did you use to get the sum? I'm genuinely interested.  I'm only an engineer and not a mathematician, so I don't know all the tools that can be brought to bear for summations

Comment: @RobertIsrael $c_m = c_{-m}$ indeed holds, since the sum arises as the $m$th Fourier series coefficient of $1/(1 - a \cos x)$.